# How to list all the shortcuts that is active in XUbuntu?

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I have a shortcut key that I use to switch to **right** workspace which is `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Right Arrow` and recently I cannot use this shortcut for some reasons, but after I reset the key in the `Window Manager` tool I can do it without any problem, my guess is that a program overwrites the key after launching the system, I want to know if there is any way that I can print a list of active shortcuts to see which program overwrites it?

Answer (score 6):

Following command will list all shortcut keys in xfce desktop (Xubuntu):

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -lv
```

You can see your custom shortcut keys with

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p /commands/custom -l -v
```

You can remove a custom shortcut with the command like

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p '/commands/custom/<Alt>F2' -r -R
```

This will only allow you to list global shortcut keys that are defined within the xfce desktop environemnt. Global shortcuts are shortcuts that are active independent of which window is in focus. Also applications can define global shortcuts, e.g. screenrecording apps that define shortcuts to start or stop them. Such global keys, however, will be active only when the application is running.

There is no generic way, if there is a way at all, to list global keys set by a specific application (it needs to be running for these keys to be active) or to list application specific shortcut keys.